# Is it possible to support HTTP Cookies with WS2007FederationHttpBinding in WCF?

Tags: wcf

We have a requirement to enable WCF client that uses WS2007FederationHttpBinding over AWS' Application Load Balancer with stickiness enabled.

```
Client --> ALB --> Server1, Server2
```

ALB attaches a ALB cookie each time so that the client can always talk to the same server during the life of session. The client performs several roundtrips per session, and each time it can receive a ALB cookie but unable to send them back when making a subsequent request, as if it doesn't care about HTTP Cookies at all. Is there a way to enable HTTP Cookies on WCF Client using WS2007FederationHttpBinding?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use cookies in WCF client by controlling http header:

```
using ( new OperationContextScope( client.InnerChannel ) )
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    request.Headers["Cookie"] = "value";
 
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[
        HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;
 
    client.Test();
}
```

We interact directly with HTTP messages exchanged with web services, reading and writing cookies as strings in the appropriate headers.

In situations where cookies must be managed in the same way for all web services called from client applications, the best option is to choose a centralized solution by applying a very useful feature (message inspector) in WCF.

We can implement the IClientMessageInspector interface on the client to handle cookies, For more information on how to use cookies in WCF clients, you can refer to this link:

https://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/